# Getting this warning; Output 0 of BackwardHookFunctionBackward is a view and is being modified inplace

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision, autograd

I am using pytorch-hooks for implementing grad-cam but it is always giving warning whenever intput is given to torchvision model. Autograd backward call is passing.

`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:1204: UserWarning: Output 0 of BackwardHookFunctionBackward is a view and is being modified inplace. This view was created inside a custom Function (or because an input was returned as-is) and the autograd logic to handle view+inplace would override the custom backward associated with the custom Function, leading to incorrect gradients. This behavior is deprecated and will be forbidden starting version 1.6. You can remove this warning by cloning the output of the custom Function. (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/variable.cpp:547.) result = torch.relu_(input)`

I have checked the post here , trying to fix the warning but I am still getting the warning.
[Custom Autograd Function Backward pass not Called](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-autograd-function-backward-pass-not-called/71065)

**Here is my code**

```
class _Grad():
  def __init__(self,model,target_layer=None,input_size = [3,224,224]):
    
    if not isinstance(model,torch.nn.Module):
      raise ValueError("Provide a valid model")
    self.model = model
    self.model_dic = dict(model.named_modules())
    
    if target_layer is None or target_layer not in self.model_dic.keys():
      raise ValueError("Provide a valid layer")
    self.target_layer = self.model_dic[target_layer]
    
    self.activations = None
    self.grads = None
    self.hooks = []
    back_hook = 'register_full_backward_hook' if torch.__version__ >= '1.8.0' else 'register_backward_hook'
    self.hooks.append(self.target_layer.register_forward_hook(self._extract_activations))
    self.hooks.append(getattr(self.target_layer,back_hook)(self._extract_grads))

  def _extract_activations(self,module,input,output):
      self.activations = output.data

  def _extract_grads(self,module,input,output):
      self.grads = output[0].data

  def _backpropagate(self,class_indx,scores):
    if self.activations is None:
      raise TypeError("Input needs to be passed before Backpropagation")
    loss = scores[:,class_indx].sum()
    self.model.zero_grad()
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)

  def _get_weights(self,class_indx,scores):
    self._backpropagate(class_indx,scores)
    b,c,h,w = self.grads.size()
    weights = self.grads.view(b, c, -1).mean(2)
    weights = weights.view(b,c,1,1)
    return weights.clone()

  def get_cam_map(self,class_indx,scores,normalized):
    weights = self._get_weights(class_indx,scores)
    
    cams = torch.nansum((weights*self.activations).squeeze(0),0)
    cams = F.relu(cams)
    if normalized :
      cam_map_min, cam_map_max = cams.min(), cams.max()
      cams = (cams - cam_map_min).div(cam_map_max)
    return cams

  def __call__(self,class_indx,scores,normalized=True):
    return self.get_cam_map(class_indx,scores,normalized)
    
from torchvision.models import densenet121
model = densenet121(pretrained=True).eval()
img = read_image("image.png")
input_tensor = normalize(resize(img, (224, 224)) / 255., [0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
extract = _Grad(model=model,target_layer="features")
out = model(input_tensor.unsqueeze(0))
```

Comment: This code is a bit confusing for me. Assuming the forward pass is `get_cam_map`, why does the forward pass class the `_backpropagate ` function?
Usually, the operation performed by the back-propagation pass is not part of the forward pass. Is there a special reason to nest them?

Comment: One or more activations in the model have inplace = True set. This is leading to error. For fix and details refer: https://github.com/frgfm/torch-cam/issues/72. The discussion is also by the OP but I am linking it here for sake of completeness